Multiply array of matrices with array of vectors in Numpy
I have an array of matrices A of shape A.shape = (N, 3, 3) and an array of vectors V of shape V.shape = (N, 3). I want to get an (N, 3) array, where each vector is the result of multiplying the i-th matrix with the i-th vector. Such as:
result = [A[i] @ V[i] for i in range(N)]

Is there a way of doing this without looping using NumPy? Ideally, I would also like this to work with arrays of higher dimensions, such as A.shape = (N, M, 3, 3) and V.shape = (N, M, 3, 3)

Note that Numpy is not efficient for operating on 3x3 matrices. A native code or a Numba code can be much faster than Numpy. I thing using a better memory layout like 3x3xNxM can make this even faster (both with Numba and Numpy).

I just refactored my whole code to have this memory layout, due to numpy's broadcasting rules. As far as I understand numpy always uses the last dimensions to deal with broadcasting ((N, M, 3) + (3,) is fine, but (3, N, M) + (3,) gives an error). Why is the other layout faster?

Because it is more SIMD friendly. SIMD units on modern x86-64 CPUs can typically compute 16x 32-bit floats per cycle, or 8x 64-bit floats. With the current layout only a fraction of the SIMD units can be used (only 3 items). As for Numpy, it is not optimized to operate on axis with only few items (and will certainly never be).

I would recommend using np.einsum(). It allows for efficient matrix multiplication across multiple dimensions without explicit loops. (ref)
Here's how you can use this:
import numpy as np

def matrix_vector_multiply(A, V):
    return np.einsum('...ij,...j->...i', A, V)

This solution works for both the case where A.shape = (N, 3, 3) and V.shape = (N, 3), as well as higher dimensions like A.shape = (N, M, 3, 3) and V.shape = (N, M, 3).
I have tested the above function and compared it with your looped solution:
N = 5
A1 = np.random.rand(N, 3, 3)
V1 = np.random.rand(N, 3)

result1_loop = np.array([A1[i] @ V1[i] for i in range(N)])
result1_einsum = matrix_vector_multiply(A1, V1)

print("Loop result shape:", result1_loop.shape)
print("Einsum result shape:", result1_einsum.shape)
print("Results match:", np.allclose(result1_loop, result1_einsum))

Here's the output:

Loop result shape: (5, 3) Einsum result shape: (5, 3) Results match:
True

This post would also help better understand einsum
